# AutoDesk Infrastructure Studio - How to enable POST for WFS services?

Tags: wfs, mapguide, autodesk, http-post

I'm attempting to get feature info with the following url:

SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=ns75382197:MAPSHEET_GRID

With many, many typenames listed after this first one.  Is there any way to enable the POST service analogous to this GET request?

Comment: Posted on autodesk forum: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-MapGuide-Enterprise/How-to-enable-POST-for-Infrastructure-Map-Server-Web-Feature/td-p/3921861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the size of a querystring (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits)